# Converting null values in date column to "N/A" in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

We have a date column which has a lot of Null Values. We want to replace these null values with "N/A", however for date columns I dont see aliases where I can change it with a click of a button.

So I wrote the following calculation :

```
IFNULL(str([Arrival Date]),"N/A")
```

Since this calculation is now a string, I cannot change the format of the date like I could for any normal date column.

Since this new calculated field has string values, I know i cannot convert it back to date. So how can i now handle the date formats ?

Comment: what is the datatype of Arrival Date in database?

Comment: its a string since it has hardcoded "N/A" which we used to replace nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BLANK` is the default value for `NULL`in Tableau.

Set how tableau treats these values

1. Right Click Measure> Format
2. Select Special Values (bottom most) and
   change the value to **NA**

See this screenshot

[image]

In case it's a discrete value refer to [Tableau KB: Replacing Null Literals](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/replacing-null-literals)